# Cant deserialize XML with type attribute

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I cant get the following XML deserialized because of the "type" attribute.

What I've tried so far:

The XML I want to deserialize:

```
<foundEntities>
    <staticGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns1:StaticGroupType">
      <number>10000</number>
      <name>Gruppe A</name>
    </staticGroup>
</foundEntities>
```

The Class:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false, ElementName = "foundEntities")]
public class FoundEntities
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "staticGroup", Namespace = "")]
   public StaticGroup staticGroup { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "staticGroup")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(StaticGroupType))]
public class StaticGroup
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "number")]
    public string number { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class StaticGroupType : StaticGroup
{
}
```

Probably I am blind but what do I miss here? Any hint is highly appreciated.

---

I have generated the classes using https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and it gave me the following output:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "staticGroup")]
public class FoundStaticGroup
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "foundEntities")]
public class FoundGroupEntities
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "staticGroup")]
    public StaticGroup StaticGroup { get; set; }
}
```

But what I get now is an error as already had a few times before:

> "The specified type was not recognized: name='StaticGroupType', namespace='http://com.f24.soap.fwi.schema', at ."

Comment: Plug your XML in here and compare the code it generates with yours: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This I already tried before and I've got always the same error as in my edited post above.

Comment: Put sample data into your classes and serialize.  Then look at xml.  The issue is with inherited classes.  When you have inherited classes it requires the type attribute to work.  So you input xml file have to look like the serialized output xml.

Comment: Hi jdweng. The XML i get is a response from a service, so it is a blackbox for me. Sorry I had to mention that before maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a working solution here:

[DotNetFiddle Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ilThvh)

I'm not sure if there are external schemas but I had to remove `xsi:type="ns1:StaticGroupType"` to get it to work.  Your XML won't parse in most readers unless there is a definition for that namespace in the XML or a schema.  Not knowing what your backend service is, I can't recommend how to resolve this.

The biggest issue is you had both your classes marked with the `XmlRootAtribute` code attribute.  Only one class can represent the root in your example.  I also removed unnecessary attributes like `Namespace` that don't have any impact since you are using the default namespace.

**Update**

The issue here is with the incoming XML it is not complete, it needs a schema reference to be able to resolve the `StaticGroup` type.  You will have to contact the people on the backend to fix this, or strip that part of the XML manually.  Correct XML would be as shown below:

```
<foundEntities
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://com.f24.soap.fwi.schema (url to back-end schema here)">
    <staticGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns1:StaticGroupType">
      <number>10000</number>
      <name>Gruppe A</name>
    </staticGroup>
</foundEntities>
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip. The problem is, that I have a generic way to deserialize the responses and if I first need to remove parts from the xml "manually" it gets some sort of unhandy.

Comment: See my update, If your XML example is complete then it is missing a schema location for the StaticGroup type.  It will not parse until then.